# Getting MySQL exception for old Column name missing

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, amazon-rds, ef-core-2.2

Im trying to pull a list of Runs objects where the details match the Platform field. Platform used to be called PlatformName. I've removed the old column name everywhere including the DB and code. For some reason, I keep getting this error

**MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'r0.PlatformName' in 'field list''**

Code:

```
    return Runs
        .Include("RunDetails")
        .Include("RunDetails.Proxy")
        .Include("RunDetails.Account")
        .Include("RunDetails.Account.Email")
        .Include("RunDetails.Account.Proxy")
        .Where(r => r.RunDetails.Any(rd => rd.Platform.Equals(platformName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to perform a database migration bro. Try something like this:

```bsh
PS> Add-Migration ChangingColumnPlatformName
PS> Update-Database -Migration ChangingColumnPlatformName
```